# Is There A Way to Make Regex Case Insensitive With JQuery.Validate.Unobtrusive?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, unobtrusive-validation

I am using .NET Core's client side validation to validate user input based on a regular expression.

The following is a regular expression that accepts 3 letters 'AAA' and 7 digits:

```
data-val-regex-pattern="^AAA\d{7}\b"
```

I want to make it case insensitive, so the user can type 'AAA' or 'aaa' and get the same result, but cannot find a way to do so.

I have tried:

1. Changing the regex to ^(?i)AAA\d{7}\b
2. Changing the regex to /^AAA\d{7}\b/i
3. Using | to check multiple expressions, one upper and one lower case.

But nothing has worked.

Can anyone please explain how to make an unobtrusive JavaScript regex case insensitive?

Comment: `^[Aa]{3}\d{7}\b`

Comment: That works for AAA, which was my example, but what about ABC, where each character is different and must be in a specific sequence? Doing ^[AaBbCc]{3}\d{7}\b allows you to put them in any order.

Comment: I only know what information you provide. Can you please add some examples of what should and shouldn't be matched so I can get you the correct pattern? If you want to match *any* 3 letters from the alphabet followed by 7 digits, try `^[A-Za-z]{3}\d{7}\b`.

Comment: This worked for me, based on your example: ^[Aa]{1}[Bb]{1}[Cc]{1}\d{7}\b. Thanks for your help. I will accept your answer.

Comment: Using `{1}` in a regex is pretty much always redundant

Comment: If you just wanted letters `a` through `c` matched then you could use `^[A-Ca-c]{3}\d{7}\b`

Comment: Or as @ChrisDunaway pointed out, you could just drop the `{1}`s: `^[Aa][Bb][Cc]\d{7}b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex should match the stated criteria: `^[A-Za-z]{3}\d{7}\b`

Can you provide some example data of what should and shouldn't be matched to confirm?

Great explanation of the pattern courtesy of [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/RpWejZ/3):

[image]